# How to animate activity transitions when using lists/grids/recycler views?

Tags: android, material-design, android-recyclerview, activity-transition

I am trying to implement some of the new Material Design activity animations, but the tutorials I've read only show examples where the view to be animated belong to the activity.

In my app, I am using a `RecyclerView`, so the `ImageView` is not part of the activity:

```
MainActivity                -> Where I call startActivity()
 ↳ MainFragment
  ↳ RecyclerView
   ↳ RecyclerViewAdapter
    ↳ ViewHolder
     ↳ ImageView            -> The hero imageView I'd like to animate
```

From what I read, I am supposed to start the new activity like this:

```
ActivityOptions options = ActivityOptions.makeSceneTransitionAnimation(this, (View) mImageView, "hero_image");

Intent intent = new Intent(this, SecondActivity.class);
startActivityForResult(intent, options.toBundle());
```

The question is: that `mImageView` does not belong to the `MainActivity`. How am I supposed to pass it?

Comment: "does not belong to the MainActivity" so its not visible in your Activity screen?  If it is visible then it belongs to your Activity

Comment: I meant it was not inflated directly in the activity. It's inflated in the Adapter, therefore the activity doesn't hold a reference to that view.

Comment: Not Adapter, but the view the adapter is set to, does hold reference to that imageview

Comment: When do you call `startActivity()`? Is it in response to the user clicking on one of the image items in your recycler view, for example? Also, a `RecyclerView` is a view in your activity's hierarchy just like any other view... and the `ImageView`s displayed by the recycler view are its children views. So saying that the image views don't belong to the activity is incorrect. If the Activity has a reference to the recycler view (which I assume it does), then it could potentially find it by iterating through its children views, making use of the `RecyclerView#findViewWithTag()` method, etc.

Answer (score 2):

In your example, you start the Activity in the same way. The View is part of the View Hierarchy of the Activity, so the call is still valid. When there is an exit transition, the Activity's View Hierarchy is searched for exiting Views to be used in the exit transition. It compares objects with those that are shared elements so that it doesn't exit the shared elements.

When you're using a RecyclerView, you will likely have to worry about the reenter transition. The RecyclerView can recycle any or all of the Views. If you haven't given your shared elements (or potential shared elements) unique names, you'll have to implement onMapSharedElements to ensure that the correct View is used. I always recommend that when using lists of potential shared elements that you give every element a unique transitionName (dynamically). That way the framework can automatically determine which View to use when coming back.

Comment: I think I understand that the view is part of the hierarchy of the activity, but I don't know how to get a reference to that specific `ImageView` of that specific item of the `RecyclerView`.

Comment: There are lots of ways to do this and it depends on how your app is written. If there is a user action (click listener) near the shared element that triggers the startActivity call, the clicked View can be used with findViewById to find the specific ImageView. You may have to walk up the hierarchy if the clicked View is a cousin. If the click isn't related (for example, "open checked item" button) you have to keep track of the Views in some way of your own. findViewWithTag() or findViewHolderForItemId() can be helpful. Be careful with RecyclerView -- any item off screen won't be sharable.

Comment: `onMapSharedElements` helped me with fix a transition. Thanks!